# filter records from two tables using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-8, multiple-tables

I have two table shopping_sessions and cart_addresses. **cart_addresses is linked with shopping_sessions using foreign key**. shopping_sessions table has various columns eg. company_id, is_active, order_number, and so on.

**ShoppingSession Model**

```
class ShoppingSession extends Model
{
    ............
    public function cartAddresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CartAddress::class, 'shopping_session_id');
    }
}
```

**Requirement**

If a query string is passed for search ($q), it should either match with "order_number" column in shopping_sessions table or "address_1" column in cart_addresses table of a company that the user is logged in. $companyId has an integer value.

I did tried with the following code.

```
$query = $this->shoppingSessionModel->query()
    ->with('cartAddresses');


if ( ! empty($q)) {
    //search by order number
    $query->where('order_number', 'LIKE', "%$q%");
    
    //search by shipping address
    $query->orWhereHas('cartAddresses', function($q2) use ($q) {
        $q2->where('address_1', 'LIKE', "%$q%")
            ->where('is_shipping', 1);
    });
}

$query->where('company_id', $companyId)
    ->where('is_active', 0)
    ->whereNotNull('order_number');

return $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
    limit);
```

**What is Wrong in this?**

When a search query is passed, it retrieves **all COMPANY Records** matching the text but I want to filter records of single company only. I want to add filter search query and company_id as well.

**Issue In short:**

**I want to fetch records of single company but it is returning  records of all company.**

Any help would be very much appreciated.

PS: When I debug the SQL query using toSql() it output the following

```
select * from `shopping_sessions` where (`order_number` LIKE ? or exists (select * from `cart_addresses` where `shopping_sessions`.`id` = `cart_addresses`.`shopping_session_id` and `address_1` LIKE ? and `is_shipping` = ?) and `company_id` = ? and `is_active` = ? and `order_number` is not null) and `shopping_sessions`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
```

Comment: I am not sure what output you required, can you please explain more with example?

Comment: @PrateikDarji The above query retrieves records of all company. I want to retrieve single company records matching the search criteria.

Comment: can you please debug with \Log::info($query->toSql()) before return, it will write the query so that you can check how the actual query is, check if $q is passing properly or not as well?

Comment: @PrateikDarji I have added the sql  query log in the question.

Comment: Okay, you can run this query directly to MySQL with proper data instead of '?' and check the output, does your table contain the required reference data for the company?

Comment: Yes. When $q is empty, it returns the correct results of single company.

Comment: yes it should be because when $q is empty it will not check for
`select * from cart_addresses where cart_addresses.shopping_session_id = ? and address_1 LIKE ? and is_shipping = ?`
this query so ideally you need to run this query and check weather company and session data exists or not

Comment: probably I think the problem is in data with reference id please check if data of related company id and address are exists or not.

Comment: The data are correctly filled in the database. I don't know why when the $q is set, it ignores the $companyId=xxx check.

Comment: Okay I understand, why don't you try `$query = $this->shoppingSessionModel->where('company_id', $companyId)->query()->where('is_active', 0)
    ->whereNotNull('order_number')->with('cartAddresses')`; instead of putting it last?

Comment: Tried that in the beginning. Will try with few changes and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```php
if ( ! empty($q)) {
    //search by order number

  $query->where(function ($query) use ($q) {
   
    $query->where('order_number', 'LIKE', "%$q%");
    
    //search by shipping address
    $query->orWhereHas('cartAddresses', function($q2) use ($q) {
        $q2->where('address_1', 'LIKE', "%$q%")
            ->where('is_shipping', 1);
    });
  });

}
```

I think the issue is that the orWhereHas is being triggered when the companyId is not matched, so if you group the orWhereHas it should fix it.

Comment: Yes, this was the missing point i.e. grouping the query